# Find the smallest number satisfying an equation

Tags: haskell

I need to solve this:

```
(n + a)^k < m^n
```

Given the `a`,`k`,`m`, I need to find the lowest `n` solving the inequality.

The only thing I came up with is:

```
search :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer 
search a k m = 
    if (inf!!0+a)^k < m^inf!!0) then inf!!0
```

Basically I already made a list from `[0..∞]` and I try to read every element starting from 0 but I can't go from the first element to second and on.

I can use extra equations with whatever type I want, but the `search` signature cannot be altered.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use a list comprehension and `head`:

```
search :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer 
search a k m = head [ n | n <- [0..], (n + a)^k < m^n ]
```

The list comprehension is just syntactical sugar for

```
search :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer 
search a k m = head filtered
  where
    filtered = filter pred [0..]
    pred n   = (n + a)^k < m^n
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want *list comprehension* used in [@Zeta's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42981156/2801663), you may use `dropWhile`:

```
search :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer 
search a k m = head $ dropWhile (not.(\n -> (n + a)^k < m^n)) [0..]
```

Comment: @Zeta Thank you, I'll be careful of it in future :P